# How to escape string characters in supabase js OR query?

Tags: supabase, postgrest, supabase-js

I'm trying to write a query that matches rows where a user-provided string matches one of two text array columns.

For example, imagine a table `messages` with text columns `greeting` and `goodbye`:

```js
// WORKS

const greeting = 'Hello there'
const goodbye = 'Goodbye everyone'

const { data, error } = await supabase
  .from('messages')
  .select()
  .or(`greeting.eq.${greeting},goodbye.eq.${goodbye}`)
```

This works fine. But, when the query value includes a comma, it breaks (doesn't find the correct rows). That makes sense, because I'm not escaping anything.

```js
// DOESN'T WORK

const greeting = 'Hello, there'     // <-- comma
const goodbye = 'Goodbye, everyone' // <-- comma

const { data, error } = await supabase
  .from('messages')
  .select()
  .or(`greeting.eq.${greeting},goodbye.eq.${goodbye}`)
```

(syntax via https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/or)

**What is the correct way to escape strings for PostgREST in supabase-js?** Which characters should I be escaping?

I want to be able to give it arbitrary text and make sure it will match correctly, not just work for commas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the reserved characters are:

- `,`
- `.`
- `:`
- `(`
- `)`
- `"`
- `\`

Via https://postgrest.org/en/stable/api.html#reserved-characters

> If filters include PostgREST reserved characters(`,`, `.`, `:`, `()`) you’ll have to surround them in percent encoded double quotes `%22` for correct processing.

> If the value filtered by the in operator has a double quote `"`, you can escape it using a backslash `\"`. A backslash itself can be used with a double backslash `\\`.

> Some HTTP libraries might encode URLs automatically(e.g. axios). In these cases you should use double quotes `""` directly instead of `%22`.

In my case, using Supabase, directly using double quotes seems to work:

```js
const { data, error } = await supabase
  .from('messages')
  .select()
  .or(`greeting.eq."${greeting}",goodbye.eq."${goodbye}"`) // <== note the quotes
```

Comment: Be aware that the user can also supply quotes (") in their query. A simple greeting.replace('"', '') would suffice, but I'm not sure